# Developer Credentials in URL to open Google Play and facebook

Tags: android, android-security

I received a security alert that says:
"Your app has URL credential, which is generally not something intentional." I've seen that has to do with

> "developers of apps that have leaked credentials used in urls".

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7026406

My app have urls that leads to pages on google play and facebook. It could be a violation url: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=developer_name"?

**UPDATE:** Apparently the problem is really in appodeal. I got in touch and they said: "We already know about this problem and fix it now."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Appodeal by any chance?. I'm receiving the same warning on two of my apps using Appodeal, and i know another developer which also have problems and we are beginning to think it's because the Appodeal SDK

Comment: No problem. It's a good mistake to make.Welcome to SO. Enjoy your stay and we look forward to your continued answers and comments

Comment: Yes @BaksaiAndrés, this warning was just the app that i used appodeal.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine answer. Appodeal did not get in touch with me, but I figured it out on my own. I also answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37872386/211457  Since removing Appodeal was the solution to the problem, and that's what this answer suggests, I recommend accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that If you are using the Appodeal SDK you will get this alert as developer. I have contacted Appodeal support and this is their answer:

> Ivan Prokopenko: Hi Pablo! we found the problem. It was problem with network, we contacted with support of network. We'll update SDK in next future, it will solve the problem. but don't worry, it's not critical