# Google Play warning: Your App may be leaking developer credentials

Tags: android, google-play, android-security

Please, explain me, what is it?

I have received a message from GP, with this text:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We detected that your app(s) listed at the end of this email are
>   potentially leaking credentials used to make network requests (HTTP
>   and FTP).
>
> Please check for cases where you use url-encoded basic access
>   authentication, for example a URL such as
>   https://username:password@www.example.com/. We recommend that you
>   immediately change the credentials and redesign your app to avoid
>   including them.
>
> Next steps
>
> ```
> Sign in to your Developer Console and submit the updated version of your app.
> Check back after five hours - we’ll show a warning message if the app hasn’t been updated correctly.
> ```
>
> Exposed developer credentials can allow an attacker to compromise your
>   systems which puts user data at risk. For other technical questions
>   about the vulnerability, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the
>   tag “android-security.”
>
> We’re here to help
>
> If you feel we have sent this warning in error, you can contact our
>   developer support team.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team

I don't understand what a problem with my app, please help me. What should I change in my app?

Comment: How are you sending username and password?

Comment: As explained in the message, check out the outgoing connections of your app, and make sure you don't send passwords in the URL, such as  http://username:password@www.example.com/.

Comment: As addition to @rupps' comment - if you must to do that, ensure you use SSL encrypted transmission.

Comment: Sending what? I'm not sending any userdata in my app, except data for log in Google Play Game Service for users. Are you talking about this?

Comment: I´ve talked to a few people who have received this email. Nobody is using any user credentials in their apps. Maybe a mistake of Google or something related to some ad sdks

Comment: I'm not use any operations with Internet, except GPGS. But I use for this instructions from Google docs. What can I do for fixing this problem? Or GP just recommend to check my app for prophylaxis? And it is not a violation on my part?

Comment: @rupps No. You are wrong. First you seem to not really understand how networking is layered (check i.e. what's TCP, IP, and where is HTTP in it). In brief - SSL connection is established first (see how [SSL handshake works](http://www.pierobon.org/ssl/ch2/detail.htm)). Then all the data, **incl. HTTP requests** is exchanged encrypted. No router will see request details (nor it needs for routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy, Pablo and others wonderful people, who  have visited this topic.

The problem was solved recently.

All you need to do - just  update Appodeal SDK to the last one (ver. 1.14.15).

You can find it in our [docs](http://appodeal.com/sdk)

Also you can download Android SDK [here](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/appodeal-android/Appodeal_Android_1.14.15.zip) (Native Android).

Regards,
Andrew

Appodeal Support Team.

Answer (score 4):

I was including Appodeal library in my free and premium app. I got this warning recently, I removed Appodeal and no longer have the warning in Google Play. Even though I wasn't using ads in Premium, I was including the Appodeal library in the binary as they are different flavors of the same Android Studio project. Looks like their problem. I had removed Appodeal from my free app a couple days ago for a different reason (https://medium.com/@greenrobotllc/response-to-1-star-review-problem-ads-auto-opening-app-store-on-lolcats-android-f1c7b7991caa#.milc5rcvs). A day or so after the free update to Google, I got this exact email about the premium version which I hadn't updated.

So check your 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Yes, I use Appodeal too. I'll update their sdk. And the problem will go away, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that If you are using the Appodeal SDK you will get this alert as developer. I have contacted Appodeal support and this is their answer:

> **Ivan Prokopenko:** Hi Pablo! we found the problem. It was problem with network, we contacted with support of network.  We'll update SDK in next future, it will solve the problem. but don't worry, it's not critical

Answer (score 1):

mytarget SDK has the same problem like Appodeal SDK. We have contacted mytarget support too and this is their answer:

> Hello Yan, Thank you for reaching out.
>
> No credentials and any personal data was involved, so no problem with
>   leaking any data with our SDK.  But to prevent the Google Play to
>   display the warning yesterday we updated our SDK - latest version is
>   4.5.1. Here is the change log - "Changed format of internal constant, because of which Google Play could display warning».
>
> So for your next update you can update our SDK. You can download
>   latest version there -
>   https://bintray.com/mytarget/maven/mytarget-sdk/view#files/com/my/target/mytarget-sdk
>
> Please let me know if you have any questions.

So check your 3rd party libraries.